# combine two continious and one discrete plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My input:

```
foo <- c(5,17,31,9,17,10,30)
bar <- c(28,16,29,14,34,6,18)
day <- c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Suday")
df <- data.frame(foo, bar, day)
```

I trying combine two bar plots:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=day, y=foo)) +  geom_col() +coord_flip()
ggplot(df, aes(x=day, y=bar)) +  geom_col() +coord_flip()
```

I want present in one plot side by side columns from two continuous variables(`foo` and `bar`) in my `y-axis` and one discrete variable `day` in my `x-axis`.  So for `y-axis` use `foo` **and** `bar` and for `x-axis` use `day`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring your data in long format with `pivot_longer`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -day
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=day, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

or without `coord_flip`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -day
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=day, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]